# Passing input from one frame to another(JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Here's the thing...

I have 2 GUI programs.
A Menu Program,which is basically a frame with buttons of food items,the buttons when clicked
opens this other program,an Input Quantity Program,which is a frame with a text field,buttons for numbers,buttons for Cancel and Confirm. The quantity that is confirmed by the user will be accessed by the menu program from the Input Quantity Program to be stored in a vector so that every time a user wants to order other food items he will just click another button and repeat the process.

Now I've coded the most part and got everything working except one thing,the value returned by the Input Quantity Program has this delay thing.

This is what I do step by step:

1)Click a food item in Menu,it opens the Input Quantity window.
2)I input the number I want,it displayed in the text box correctly.
3)I pressed confirm which will do 3 things,first it stores the value of the text field to a variable,second it will call the dispose() method and third a print statement showing the value of the variable(for testing purposes).
4)The menu program then checks if the user has already pressed the Confirm button in the Input program,if true it shall call a method in the Input program called getQuantity() which returns the value of the variable 'quantity' and store it in the vector.
5)After which executes another print statement to check if the passed value is correct and then calls the method print() to show the ordered item name and it's recorded quantity.

Here are the screenshots of the GUI and the code will be below it.

[image: MENU GUI]
[image: 1st order]
[image: last order]

ActionPerformed method of the CONFIRM BUTTON in the Input Quantity Program:

```
private void ConfirmButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    confirmed = true;
    q= textField.getText().toString();
    quantity =Integer.parseInt(q) ;
    System.out.println("getQTY method inside Input Quantity Interface:" +getQuantity());
    System.out.println("Quantity from confirmButton in Input Quantity Interface actionPerformed: "+quantity);

    //getQuantity();
}
```

ACTION LISTENER CLASS of the MENU ITEM BUTTONS in MENU PROGRAM which does step 2 above:

```
class f implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         inputGUI.setVisible(true);
         int  q =0;

          q=inputGUI.getQuantity(); //call method to get value from Input Program

          System.out.println("Quantity inside Menu actionperformed from AskQuantity interface: "+q);

         orderedQuantity.add(q); //int vector
         textArea.append("\n"+e.getActionCommand()+"\t"+ q);
         orderedItems.add(e.getActionCommand());  //String vector
         print();
         /*
         System.out.println("Enter QTY: ");
         int qty = in.nextInt();
         orderedQuantity.add(qty);
         print();*/
   }
```

Here are screenshots of the print statements in the console:
Here I first ordered Pumpkin Soup,I entered a quantity of 1
[image: 1st Order]

Here I ordered seafood marinara and entered a quantity of 2
[image: 2nd order]

Here I ordered the last item,pan fried salmon and entered a quantity of 3

[image]

As you can see the first recorded quantity is 0 for the first item I ordered then when I added another item,the quantity of the first item gets recorded but the 2nd item's quantity is not recorded..same goes after the third item... and the quantity of the 3rd item is not recorded even if the program terminates :(

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can help you without code. How much code? It's hard to say, except "enough to show the problem, but not too much to overwhelm us with unrelated code." Best if you could create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org) but that would require a lot of effort on your part. If the problem is complex though, and no simple solutions are forthcoming, then this is often the best way to go. Luck.

Comment: Also, I wonder if the dependent window should be a dialog such as a JOptionPane or JDialog rather than another JFrame. Understand that these dialogs can accept JPanels loaded to the gills with a complex GUI, so don't assume that they're just for simple interactions only, and in fact far from it.

Comment: uhm actually....i chose to do the input program as a frame so that I can add buttons and a textfield.. I will edit the question and post some of the code(my code is quite messy yet lol) and a screen shot of the GUI so you get the idea.

Comment: You should use a java.Util.List instead of Vector.

Comment: @Kevin: *again* you can add buttons and textfields to a dialog. If the second window is dependent on the first, that is, it shouldn't even exist without the first, then it should be a dialog.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so how exactly can I achieve this? can you please redirect me to some tutorials or something? Thanks for the feedback too. :)

Comment: It seems that your "quantity recorded" is showing the index of your Vector and not the value (index starts in zero). Try larger values to confirm that.

Comment: @stas the vectors are a temporary thing. if you can see the screenies...it's not quite done yet. :) I just want everything to work the way their supposed to before I get to the specifics.

Comment: @SérgioMichels i actually tried inputting thousands even millions as values....and to no avail...it still passes 0 then after adding another item will it show the value I entered for the first item.

Comment: @Kevin can you post your `inputGUI.getQuantity()` method?

Comment: @Kevin: please see code sample in my answer.

Comment: @SérgioMichels it is just a `return quantity;` statement

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry for the late reply...i will look into it now.

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I see your problem, and in fact it stems directly from  you're not using a modal dialog to get your input. You are querying the inputGUI *before* the user has had a chance to interact with it. Hang on while I show you a small example of what I mean...

**Edit**
Here's my example code that has a modal JDialog and a JFrame, both acting as a dialog to a main JFrame, and both using the very same JPanel for input. The difference being the modal JDialog will freeze the code of the main JFrame at the point that it has been made visible and won't resume until it has been made invisible -- thus the code will wait for the user to deal with the dialog before it progresses, and therein holds all the difference.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DialogExample {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dialog Example");
      MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel(frame);

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MainPanel extends JPanel {
   private InputPanel inputPanel = new InputPanel();
   private JTextField responseField = new JTextField(10);
   private JDialog inputDialog;
   private JFrame inputFrame;

   public MainPanel(final JFrame mainJFrame) {
      responseField.setEditable(false);
      responseField.setFocusable(false);

      add(responseField);
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Open Input Modal Dialog") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (inputDialog == null) {
               inputDialog = new JDialog(mainJFrame, "Input Dialog", true);
            }
            inputDialog.getContentPane().add(inputPanel);
            inputDialog.pack();
            inputDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(mainJFrame);
            inputDialog.setVisible(true);  

            // all code is now suspended at this point until the dialog has been 
            // made invisible

            if (inputPanel.isConfirmed()) {
               responseField.setText(inputPanel.getInputFieldText());
               inputPanel.setConfirmed(false);
            }
         }
      }));
      add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Open Input JFrame") {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (inputFrame == null) {
               inputFrame = new JFrame("Input Frame");
            }

            inputFrame.getContentPane().add(inputPanel);
            inputFrame.pack();
            inputFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(mainJFrame);
            inputFrame.setVisible(true);  

            // all code continues whether or not the inputFrame has been
            // dealt with or not.

            if (inputPanel.isConfirmed()) {
               responseField.setText(inputPanel.getInputFieldText());
               inputPanel.setConfirmed(false);
            }

         }
      }));
   }
}

class InputPanel extends JPanel {
   private JTextField inputField = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton confirmBtn = new JButton("Confirm");
   private JButton cancelBtn = new JButton("Cancel");
   private boolean confirmed = false;

   public InputPanel() {
      add(inputField);
      add(confirmBtn);
      add(cancelBtn);

      confirmBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            confirmed = true;
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(InputPanel.this);
            win.setVisible(false);
         }
      });
      cancelBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            confirmed = false;
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(InputPanel.this);
            win.setVisible(false);
         }
      });
   }

   public boolean isConfirmed() {
      return confirmed;
   }

   public void setConfirmed(boolean confirmed) {
      this.confirmed = confirmed;
   }

   public String getInputFieldText() {
      return inputField.getText();
   }
}
```

So solution: use a modal JDialog.

Comment: I see. I'll test your sample code so I can fully understand it. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I'm sure this is the solution to my problem...however I'm having trouble implementing this to my GUI.
I used Netbeans' GUI Builder to create the MENU Interface.

What am I going to put as the Frame parameter in public `MainPanel(final JFrame mainJFrame)`...my main frame class is called  Test which extends JFrame. i tried inputting `MainPanel(new Test());` but nothing shows up,even the MENU Interface.

Comment: I know some manual coding of GUI. So I've kinda understood this example.

Comment: nevermind got it to work. :)
this helped alot. thanks again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i am having two GUI frames f1 and f2. Now by clicking a button on f1 i want to invoke frame f2 and also sending some data from f1(frame class) to f2(frame class).
One possible way is to declare a constructor in f2 which takes the same data as parameters which i wanted to send to it from f1.Now in frame f1's coding just include these statements:
f1.setVisible(false);//f1 gets invisible
f2 newFrame=new f2(uname,pass);//uname and pass have been takenfrom f1's text fields
f2.setVisible(true);

I think this will clear up your problem.

Comment: i actually tried this yesterday...and it kinda messed up everything else. so yeah didnt solve my problem, thanks anyway..